# FileMaker - How to create a new record in another table for each record in a found set

Tags: filemaker

I want a user to be able to do a search in the layout/table "Cages" and then click a button to run a script that will create a new record in a table called "CagesProtocolLineHistory" for each record in the found set.

Below is what I have so far which almost works but on go to original layout line it doesn't go to the next record, it goes to a record near the end. I.e., it's skipping some records.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, seems to be working now.  It did add a "go to record/request/page [first]" to the top of the script.  I wonder if that matters.

Comment: I'll close this on Monday if it's still working properly and the issue doesn't come back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Go to Record[ first ]` before the loop will ensure that all records are copied. Otherwise, if the script starts at some record other than first, it will skip all records before this.

A couple of notes: FileMaker string comparison is case-insensitive by default, so you don't need to use `Upper()` here. Also, in most cases it's simpler not to copy all data through variables, but pass a single key and copy other data via lookups.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a three step: search for the "yes"s in a new window; export the record ids (passed params) to a local temp file, and reimport the ids into the child table.